# "Created by" Opensea Minter vs. Contract deployer

Tags: opensea

Hello I am deploying a contract for a NFT Art markeplace.

On OS, the "created by" field automatically shows the username of the contract deployer ("E57899" - the marketplace) and not the one of the minter (Artist_pietro the artist that minted the NFT).

Other markeplaces (Foundation / Superrare) seem to have the "created by field" populated by the address of the creator/ minter even if the collection and the contract deployer is the markeplace. Do you know why?

Doesn't seem to be anything related to the metadata unfortunately

Here is the NFT from my markeplace https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x4b3f1b37d195d09f69b99175476e59759f2e9d2a/6

Here is a NFT from Foundation https://opensea.io/assets/0x3b3ee1931dc30c1957379fac9aba94d1c48a5405/50612

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Foundation..

When you create and Mint a NFT in Foundation, You will use Foundation's Smartcontract to mint the token, therefore it will appear under foundation collection,

The same is for the old Rarible collection,
In the past, when you created and minted NFT in Rarible, You'd use Rarible SmartContract to mint the token therefore it would appear under the same collection.

Both old Rarible and foundation smart contracts save a lot of info about the minter in order to generate the metadata that will give the token its appearance but basically you are using their SmartContracts.

Mind that 1 smartcontract = 1 collection

So,,

When you mint, they generate the metadata of that specific token, store it and map the tokenID to a whole bunch of information that they take from the author..